# Continuous functions on a compact Hausdorff space

Tags: functional-analysis

Are there any nice properties that characterize the space $C(K)$, where $K$ is compact Hausdorff? I mean results on the whole space (not each function in particular), for example, is it true that $C(K)$ is compact itself? Hausdorff?
Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

$C(K)$ will not generally be compact.  However, the [Arzela-Ascoli theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arzel%C3%A0%E2%80%93Ascoli_theorem), which characterizes some compact subsets, applies.

Of course, $C(K)$ is Hausdorff if its topology is taken relative to the [uniform metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_norm) $\|\cdot\|_\infty$, which is often the case.  In general, $C(K)$ is taken to be a metric space of some kind, and all metric spaces are Hausdorff.

[This is a helpful list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_functions_on_a_compact_Hausdorff_space) of various other nice properties that such spaces have.